# Keycloak after login gets in loop

Tags: java, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0, servlet-filters

I am securing my java application using Keycloak saml for that I am using SamlFilter but after successful login it is just continuous redirecting it again and again in loop.
My keycloak-saml.xml file:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>APP</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.saml.servlet.SamlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>APP</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also added keycloal-saml.xml file in WEB-INF folder as below:

```
<keycloak-saml-adapter>
<SP entityID="Sample"
    sslPolicy="EXTERNAL"
    logoutPage="logout">
    <Keys>
        <Key signing="true">
            <PrivateKeyPem>
                <!-- Private Key -->
            </PrivateKeyPem>
            <CertificatePem>
              <!-- Certi Key -->
            </CertificatePem>
        </Key>
    </Keys>
    <IDP entityID="idp"
         signatureAlgorithm="RSA_SHA256"
         signatureCanonicalizationMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
         metadataUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml/descriptor">
        <SingleSignOnService signRequest="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             validateAssertionSignature="false"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             bindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"/>
        <SingleLogoutService signRequest="true"
                             signResponse="true"
                             validateRequestSignature="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             responseBinding="POST"
                             postBindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"
                             redirectBindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"/>
         <Keys>
            <Key signing="true">
                <KeyStore resource="/WEB-INF/keystore.jks" password="store123">
                    <Certificate alias="Sample"/>
                </KeyStore>
            </Key>
        </Keys>
    </IDP>
</SP>
```

And keycloak setting is as below:

[image]

But after login it keycloak redirects to my application but my application again redirects to Keycloak and it shows below message and this happening in loop:

[image]

I know there must some setting is missing.

Comment: Which kc version are u using?

Comment: @dreamcrash I am using quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0

Comment: Hard to say. You have to dig into so logs and see what it says during the loop